What is '..density..' doing in Lets-Plot histogram
My understanding of a density histogram is that the value associated with bin i:

with a frequency of fi
a sample size of n
a bin width of w
density di = (fi / n)/w

For this test case, the frequency and probability histograms are as I expect, but the density histogram isn't. Bin 1 for example has a frequency of 3. given n = 20 and w =.1 I would expect a density of .75 (which np.histogram calculates) but the plot indicates .84.
Is my understanding of density faulty, am i implementing it incorrectly, or is something broken?
This code demonstrates the problem.
Lets-Plot is version 4.3.3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from lets_plot import *
LetsPlot.setup_html()

rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)

test = rng.normal(0, 1, (20, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['A', 'B'])

plot_1 = (
    ggplot(df, aes(x='A')) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth=.2, fill='pink') +
    ggtitle('Frequency')
)

plot_2 = (
    ggplot(df, aes(x='A')) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y='..density..'),binwidth=.2, fill='pink') +
    ggtitle('Density')
)

plot_3 = (
    ggplot(df, aes(x='A')) +
    geom_histogram(aes(weight=np.ones_like(df.A) / len(df.A)),binwidth=.2, fill='pink') +
    ggtitle('Probability')
)

# to calculate the same distribution using np.histogram, force an appropriate set of bins:
bins = np.arange(-1.56, 2.5, .2)
freq, edges = np.histogram(df.A,  bins=bins)
print('Frequency by bin calculated by np.histogram:')
print(f'{'Bin':^5s}{'Freq':^5s}')
for i,f in enumerate(freq):
    print(f'{i+1:^5d}{f:^5d}')
print('')
    
plot_1.show()
plot_3.show()

dens, edges = np.histogram(df.A, density='True', bins=bins)
print('Density by bin calculated by np.histogram:')
print(f'{'Bin':^5s}{'Density':^9s}')
for i,d in enumerate(dens):
    print(f'{i+1:^5d}{d:^9.2f}')
print('')
plot_2.show()





It looks like aes(y='..density..') is using the trapezium rule to calculate the area under the histogram when calculating the density, which is slightly underestimating the area underneath the histogram that you get from just summing the counts and multiplying by the bin width, e.g., if you do:
counts, edges = np.histogram(df.A, density=False, bins=bins)
print(counts / np.trapz(counts, edges[:-1] + 0.1))
[0.83333333 0.55555556 0.         0.55555556 0.27777778 0.27777778
 0.         0.55555556 0.         0.27777778 0.27777778 0.83333333
 0.27777778 0.         0.27777778 0.         0.27777778 0.
 0.         0.27777778]

you get the same values that you are seeing in the plot.

Thanks you, that appears to be what's going on. I'm not a stats person, do you know if this is a commonly applied technique for calculating density histograms? I suppose I can see the logic, and make a case for it, but I've not run across it before.

I can only assume that they don't expect you to be using the ..density.. option for binned histograms, but instead expect it to be used for more continuous distributions. That said, if you had lots of points and no gaps in the bins you probably wouldn't notice the difference.

It appears there was a bug in the density computation in the lets-plot histogram: https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot/issues/1157
Hopefully, the sum of areas in histogram will be 1 in a future release.
UPD: the issue is fixed in v4.4.1
